# Remove default_filter from Twilio TaskRouter

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I've set up my workflows and taskqueues. 
Workflow looks like this.

```
{
  "task_routing": {
    "filters": [
      {
        "filter_friendly_name": "Dialpad",
        "expression": "flexOutboundDialerTargetWorker != null",
        "targets": [
          {
            "expression": "task.flexOutboundDialerTargetWorker == worker.contact_uri",
            "queue": "WQ044385bd3c00a98cc63c092d02e5b571",
            "timeout": 10
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "default_filter": {
      "queue": "WQ044385bd3c00a98cc63c092d02e5b571"
    }
  }
}
```

Task queue and workers are configured so that `WQ044385bd3c00a98cc63c092d02e5b571` has available workers.

However, when I call the number, a task gets created, a reservation is made, but in the case that nobody os available, the task moves to the `default_filter`and it stays there forever.

What I want to do?

- Remove the `default_filter` or set a timeout on it (can't really figure out how to edit the default filter)
- Handle the canceled task myself using `Event Callbacks`

Comment: Can you gain some general insight from this document, looking at the Task Router piece, Implementing Voicemail with Twilio Flex, TaskRouter, and WFO, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021082934-Implementing-Voicemail-with-Twilio-Flex-TaskRouter-and-WFO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a visual option I missed located at:

`https://www.twilio.com/console/taskrouter/workspaces/WSXXX/workflows`

Scroll to bottom and set the `DEFAULT QUEUE` to `None`.